# PL/SQL Optional parameters in where

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would really appreciate the help with this consultation

I would like to know how to set optional parameters in the where

```
WHERE T.ID_NUM = :ID_NUM
OR ASOL.CASE_ID = :CASE_ID
```

for example:

1. ID_NUM cannot have any value in the parameter, but CASE_ID does have a value in the parameter
2. ID_NUM has a value in the parameter, but CASE_ID has no value in the parameter
3. ID_NUM has value in parameter and CASE_ID has value in parameter

when I say it has no value the parameter is empty or "undefined"

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
WHERE (T.ID_NUM = :ID_NUM OR :ID_NUM IS NULL) AND
      (ASOL.CASE_ID = :CASE_ID OR :CASE_ID IS NULL)
```

I am guessing you actually want `AND`, not `OR` between the conditions.

Comment: This also  results in true if both are null. Is that valid as per the requirement?

Comment: @Vijay makes a good point here: if both are NULL the query would return the entire table which is probably not desirable.  You most likely want to add AND (:ID_NUM IS NOT NULL OR :CASE_ID IS NOT NULL).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a NVL function in your clause, if you send a null value in the parameters, then the query are going to use the second comparisson and the second comparisson always be true

```
WHERE  T.ID_NUM     = NVL(:ID_NUM  , T.ID_NUM    )
  OR   ASOL.CASE_ID = NVL(:CASE_ID , ASOL.CASE_ID)
```